# Filling array with numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have such situation:
There is **8** div-blocks with ids like 'rateN_wrapper' where is 'N' is the number of div:

```
<div id="rate1_wrapper">
  <a href="#" id="0_1">...</a>
  <a href="#" id="0_2">...</a>
  <a href="#" id="0_3">...</a>
</div>

<div id="rate2_wrapper">
  <a href="#" id="1_1">...</a>
  <a href="#" id="1_2">...</a>
  <a href="#" id="1_3">...</a>
</div>

...

var ratings = new Array();
for (i=0; i < 8; i++)
{
    ratings[i] = -1; // Default is unrated

}

for (i=0; i < 8; i++)
{
    $('#rate' + i + '_wrapper a').click(function() {
        ratings[i] = parseInt( $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1] );
        console.debug(ratings);
    });
}
```

My work is to fill array in need place with clicked link's id (parsed). But it's always changes only latest element of array (8). Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a problem caused by the closure in the for loop. You could lookup the id by parsing the parent id:

```
for (i=0; i < 8; i++)
{ 
  $('#rate' + i + '_wrapper a').click(function() {
    var parentId = $(this).parent('div').attr('id');
    var index = /\d/.exec(parentId);
    ratings[index] = parseInt( $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1] );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the function you create is closing over the i variable. It sees a reference to i at its current value instead of the value when you created the function. After the for loop exits, i will be 8, so all your anonymous functions will update `ratings[8]`. I think this might fix it:

```
for (i=0; i < 8; i++)
{
    var idx = i;
    $('#rate' + idx + '_wrapper a').click(function() {
        ratings[idx] = parseInt( $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1] );
        console.debug(ratings);
    });
}
```

I'm not sure if declaring the var inside the loop body will rebind it for every iteration. If so, then the anonymous function will only see the value that `idx` had at the time the function was created. Here is a way that I know will work:

```
function CreateHandler(idx) {
    return function() {
        ratings[idx] = parseInt( $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1] );
        console.debug(ratings);
    }
}

for (i=0; i < 8; i++) {
    $('#rate' + idx + '_wrapper a').click(CreateHandler(i));
}
```

So you create a function that will create an anonymous function with the correct index. The returned anonymous function will see the value of `idx` at the time of its creation.

Comment: It would also be possible to avoid the for loop completely by using jquery .each() which might be more clear

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, the first example will work if you declare var idx = i inside the anonymous function body instead of the outer loop body...

Comment: @jarrett I can't use each() here, I haven't static name of object.

Comment: You don't need a static name to use each